# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy', in Sublime IDE(Python)

Tags: python, numpy, sublimetext, importerror, modulenotfounderror

Just downloaded Sublime text and was trying to test it. Simple programs which don't require importing anything are working just fine, but i m unable to import anything.

I tried the simple import numpy command. I tried to run it just to check if it was working and this the output that came up.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users_**\anaconda3\Lib\Sublime Text Build 3211 x64..py", line 1, in 
import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
[Finished in 4.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users_**\anaconda3\Lib\Sublime Text Build 3211 x64..py"]
[dir: C:\Users_**\anaconda3\Lib\Sublime Text Build 3211 x64]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Users_**\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users___.dotnet\tools]

BTW, numpy is installed, up to date and working on the other IDEs

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure numpy is installed, check which python environment you are trying the execute the script in.
You might have to activate the env which has numpy installed  before running your script.